# display jumps to the bottom, dosnt start at the top?

Tags: posts

help!

can anyone tell me why my blog post jumps down to the video near the bottom of the post?

it does in on every browser and 2 different machines and it does it when you enter the primary domain http://rbarnes.com  or the post url http://rbarnes.com/989/atlanta-bloggers-meetup/

click a link and let it fully load before you do anything, you'll see it jump

I took the wistia video out and left the youtube video in and it still jumped down - then I took both videos out and it still jumps down

i fixed a  tag not closed - but no help...

what is making it do this?

big thanks if you can help.

rb

this theme is eleven40 child of Genisis

Comment: It's not jumping for me. Have you tried multiple browsers? Are you pressing f5, or are you actually doing a fresh load of the page? Because many (all?) browsers jump to where you were on the page if you just refresh.

Comment: It jumps for me in Firefox when clicking the `atlanta-bloggers-meetup` URL.  There are a couple JS errors on the page as well, which should probably be addressed first to make sure they're not causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install web developer add on in firefox  and disable all script from drop down menu then refresh the page. see the result it is not moving to the video , it means **there is some javascript code in your theme that make it to move down to the video**.